# Nullable foreign key causes runtime error in OData service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I'm using OData in an ASP.NET Core Web API.

I have the following entities:

```
public class Equipment
{
    [Key]
    public long EquipmentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EquipmentCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EquipmentTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties
    [ForeignKey("CostCenterRefNavigation")]
    public int CostCenterRef { get; set; }
    public CostCenter CostCenterRefNavigation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EquipmentCatalogueRefNavigation")]
    public int? EquipmentCatalogueRef { get; set; }
    public EquipmentCatalogue EquipmentCatalogueRefNavigation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EquipmentInfoRefNavigation")]
    public int? EquipmentInfoRef { get; set; }
    public EquipmentInfo EquipmentInfoRefNavigation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EquipmentCategoryRefNavigation")]
    public int? EquipmentCategoryRef { get; set; }
    public EquipmentCategory EquipmentCategoryRefNavigation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("equipmentTypeRefNavigation")]
    public int EquipmentTypeRef { get; set; }
    public EquipmentType equipmentTypeRefNavigation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BOMRefNavigation")]
    public long? BomRef { get; set; }
    public BOM? BOMRefNavigation { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<ServiceEquipment> ServiceEquipmentRefNavigation { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<WorkOrder>? WorkOrdersRefNavigation { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<WorkOrderDocument>? WorkOrderDocumentsRefNavigation { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<EquipmentFailure> EquipmentFailuresRefNavigation { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<EquipmentFailureCause> EquipmentFailureCausesRefNavigation { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<FailureReport> FailureReportsEquipmentRefNavigation { get; set; }
}

public class EquipmentCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int EquipmentCategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CategoryCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Equipment> EquipmentsRefNavigation { get; set; }
}

public class EquipmentCatalogue
{
    [Key]
    public int EquipmentCatalogueId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RefFileName { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Equipment>? EquipmentsRefNavigation { get; set; }
}

public class EquipmentInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int EquipmentInfoId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RefFileName { get; set; }

    //Navigation Property
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Equipment>? EquipmentsRefNavigation { get; set; }
}

public class EquipmentType
{
    [Key]
    public int EquipmentTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EquipmentTypeTitle { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Equipment>? EquipmentsRefNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `program.cs` file:

```
    static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new();
        .
        .
        builder.EntitySet<Equipment>("Equipments");
        .
        .
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
.
.
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt => opt.AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel()).Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().Expand().SetMaxTop(null));
```

When I call the target endpoint using the `http://localhost:5000/odata/Equipments` query, I get an exception:

> Microsoft.OData.ODataException: The property 'EquipmentCatalogueRef[Nullable=False]' of type 'Edm.Int32' has a null value, which is not allowed.

How can I fix this error?

**Update #1**:

OData controller for Equipment entity:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [Authorize(Roles = "System,Administrator")]
    public IQueryable<Equipment> Get()
    {
        IQueryable<Equipment> eqList = _sqlServerContext.Equipments.AsQueryable();

        return eqList;
    }
```

**Update #2:** I have provided a simple project [here](https://github.com/codeblock88/temp.git). You can see the problem by url query `http://localhost:5147/odata/user?$expand=FileRefNavigation`.

Comment: Have you tried   to configure the relationship as not required ？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you should try is to make the key property and navigation one consistent i.e. either both nullable or both non-nullable:

```
[ForeignKey("EquipmentCatalogueRefNavigation")]
public int? EquipmentCatalogueRef { get; set; }
public EquipmentCatalogue? EquipmentCatalogueRefNavigation { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks. this solution solved the problem for query mentioned above. But, When I want to use expand on a nullable foreign key (`http://localhost:5000/odata/Equipments?$expand=EquipmentCategoryRefNavigation`) there is another exceptions says: `System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.`

Comment: @AlexWright can you post a [mre] somewhere? Will try to look at it later.

Comment: I have provided a sample project in my github. Please have a look on my update #2.

Comment: @ Alex Wright,I tried with your codes,only received an incomplete json,and this issue may help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036653/odata-disable-serialization-of-nullable-object